# Naming index of array element with strings in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix, indexing

Array elements:

```
4  3  2  1  5

a[1]=4
a[2]=3
a[3]=2
a[4]=1
a[5]=5
```

For Array index 1 corresponds to string name Basavaraj,

index 2 corresponds to string name Chandru,

index 3 corresponds to string name Natesh,

index 4 corresponds to string name Vijay,

index 5 corresponds to string name Raghu,

---

So if array value 4 comes at index at 1 it has to display string Basavaraj,

3 comes at index 2 means string Chandru should be displayed,

2 comes at index 3 means  string Natesh should be displayed,

1 comes at index 4 means  string Vijay should be displayed,

5 comes at index 5 means  string Raghu should be displayed,

Sample of input array values:

```
4
4
4
3
3
3
1
1
1
2
2
2
5
5
5
```

output should be according to above array elements:

```
Basavaraj
Basavaraj
Basavaraj
Chandru
Chandru
Chandru
Vijay
Vijay
Vijay
Natesh
Natesh
Natesh
Raghu
Raghu
Raghu
```

Sample of input array values:

```
5
5
5
1
1
1
2
2
2
4
4
4
3
3
3
```

output should be according to above array elements:

```
Raghu
Raghu
Raghu
Vijay
Vijay
Vijay
Natesh
Natesh
Natesh
Basavraj
Basavraj
Basavraj
Chandru
Chandru
Chandru
```

**Only 5 values are taken i.e 1 2 3 4 5**
How it can be done done in matlab?

**Alternate explanation:**
Consider below scenario:

Array:1 5 4 2 3

ind[1]=1--->Basavraj

ind[2]=5--->Chandru

ind[3]=4--->Natesh

ind[4]=2--->Vijay

ind[5]=3--->Raghu

Sample of input array:

```
2
2
4
4
5
5
1
1
3
3
```

output:

```
Vijay
Vijay
Natesh
Natesh
Chandru
Chandru
Basavraj
Basavraj
Raghu
Raghu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sth. like this:

```
% a is a cell array defined with {} containing each name in one element.
a={'Basavaraj', 'Chandru' ,'Natesh','Vijay','Raghu'};
%b is an array which has integer values from 1 to 5 (10 times) if you add more values in a b still generates random numbers for all elements (because of numel(a))
b= round((numel(a)-1)*rand(10,1)+1);
% this returns for each integer in b the according name from a (be careful to use {} to return the value, normal brackets won't work here
a{b}
```

I used `rand` to get a random order in `b` obviously you should use your vector as stated in your question.

**Edit 1**
Hey not so sure if this is what you asked (in comment):

```
List_Of_Names={'Basavaraj', 'Chandru' ,'Natesh','Vijay','Raghu'};
input1 =[1 5 4 2 3];
tmp_List_Names = List_Of_Names(input1);
input2= round((numel(List_Of_Names)-1)*rand(1,10)+1);
result =tmp_List_Names(input2);
display(input2)
display(result)
```

Here `List_Of_Names` is the list of your names. 
`input1` is the first input which defines the new order (idx(1)->5) not sure if this is what you are asking for.
`tmp_List_Names` is a temporal List which contains your names in the new order.
`input2` is that long integer list which defines the output.
`result`is the output. And at the end I use `display()` to show `input2` and `result` in the command window. Which would look like this:

```
input2 =

     3     1     5     5     3     3     2     5     2     1


result = 

    'Vijay'    'Basavaraj'    'Natesh'    'Natesh'    'Vijay'    'Vijay'    'Raghu'    'Natesh'    'Raghu'    'Basavaraj'
```

If you want them to be in Columns not rows You can either transpose `input2` and (`List_Of_Names` or `result`). Transpose is possible by adding `'` :

```
result=result';
```

Comment: My question is somewhat different please check my alternate explanation

Comment: @prashanth I edited my post. Check if thats now the result you want.